# Autofac DynamicProxy2 PropertiesAutowired not working when EnableInterfaceInterceptors and AllowCircularDependencies

Tags: c#, autofac

I use Autofac DynamicProxy2 do AOP logging.
If I register like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblys.ToArray()).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ServiceImpl"))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                .PropertiesAutowired()
                .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
                .InterceptedBy(typeof(LogInterceptor));
            ;
```

then ValuesServiceImpl instance can be auto wire to property, like this:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        public IValuesService ValuesService { get; set; }
    }
```

But if I use  PropertiesAutowired(**PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies**)

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblys.ToArray()).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ServiceImpl"))
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                    .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies)
                    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
                    .InterceptedBy(typeof(LogInterceptor));
                ;
```

then PropertiesAutowired not working, ValuesService property is null.

In my project I must allow Circular Dependencies, and I prefer use EnableInterfaceInterceptors instead of EnableClassInterceptors

Comment: You might want to take a look at your design and prevent having circular dependencies in the first place.

Comment: Thanks fore your advice, I will try.

Comment: But I still want to know how to enable interface interceptors when allow circular dependencies.